# Powershell Script to pull DMV results from Tabular Model

Tags: powershell, ssas-tabular, dmv

Trying to build a PowerShell script to connect to Analysis Services **Tabular** Model and pull the output of DMV queries(eg : SELECT * FROM $System.DBSchema_Tables)

Tried Below, but its fails, it seems there is something wrong with connection string or the way I am trying to connect:

```
$connectionString = "server=TabularServerName;database='ModelName';trusted_connection=true;";
$CubeQuery = "SELECT * FROM $System.DBSchema_Tables";

#SQL Connection - connection to SQL server
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connectionString;

#SQL Command - set up the SQL call
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection;
$sqlCommand.CommandText = $CubeQuery;

#SQL Adapter - get the results using the SQL Command
$sqlAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCommand
$dataSet = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$recordCount = $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

Comment: Tried Below, but its fails, it seems there is something wrong with connection string or the way I am trying to connect:

Comment: Try execute  $Connection.Open() after declaring $connection and post the error message

Answer (score 1):

What are you not just using the SQLPS module or [DBA Tools module](https://dbatools.io/)?

There are of course other modules you can leverage:

```
Find-Module -Name '*sql*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
Find-Package -Name '*sql*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Here is the stuff I've passed on to others messing with SQL.

> ***Install the SQL Server PowerShell module***
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver15
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/?view=sqlserver-ps
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15

Then see:

> [Connecting PowerShell to SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/connecting-powershell-to-sql-server)
>
> As an overview the following is the list of options I will go over in
>   this article:
>
> - SQL Server PowerShell (SQLPS)
> - SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)
> - .NET (System.Data.SqlClient)
>
> SQLPS
>
> SQL Server PowerShell SQLPS is a utility that was first released
>   with SQL Server 2008, you may see this referenced in various ways. It
>   exists as a (1) utility and (2) as a PS module. The utility and module
>   are installed with the SQL Server Management tools from SQL Server
>   2008 and up. There are a few ways of connecting to SQL Server using
>   this utility, and each one has strengths and weaknesses.
>
> SQLPS.exe
>
> This is a utility that you should be able to open by typing
>   it in the run prompt (Start > Run). A second option, right-click a
>   node under Object Explorer, within SQL Server Management Studio
>   (SSMS), and select “Start PowerShell”. The SQLPS utility’s main access
>   point is using the provider “SQLSERVER:\” to browse SQL Server like a
>   file directory. With that, based on the node you open SQLPS from will
>   place you within that path of the provider. Under each “folder” you
>   are in for the provider offers properties to read or set, and some
>   methods to use for administration.

```
Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SQL\LOCALHOST\SQL12\Databases | foreach { $_.RecoveryModel = "SIMPLE"; $_.Alter() }
```

> SQLPS Module
>
> Importing the SQLPS module into a PS session provides the
>   same access using the utility does but allows you to operate in the
>   PS version of the OS you operate under. In SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2
>   you will load the SQLPS as a snap-in (Add-PSSnapin), then with SQL
>   Server 2012 and up it is imported (Import-Module).

```
# Loading SMO
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo,Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

# Connecting with SMO
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server “localhost\sql12”
$srv.Databases | select name

# .NET Framework
# Create a connection
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = “Server=localhost\sql12;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=master”
$sqlConn.Open()

# Create your command (the T-SQL that will be executed)
$sqlcmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
<# or #>
$sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$query = “SELECT name, database_id FROM sys.databases”
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $query

# Create your data adapter (if you want to retrieve data)
$adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd

# Create your dataset (the adapter fills this object)
$data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adp.Fill($data) | Out-Null

# Retrieving Your Data
$data.Tables
<# or #>
$data.Tables[0]
```

***Lastly:***

[USE POWERSHELL TO GET ALL THE MEASURES FROM A 2016 TABULAR CUBE](https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/use-powershell-get-measures-2016-tabular-cube-open-power-bi-desktop-file)

> So, here’s the PowerShell script that will get the measures from a
>   cube (change the first three variables to fit your environment):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular");

$tab = "YourSSASserver";
$dbId = "ID_or_DB";
$saveas = "C:\YourFolder\{0}.dax" -f $tab.Replace('\', '_');


$as = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server;
$as.Connect($tab);
$db = $as.Databases[$dbId];
# in case you want to search by the name of the cube/db:
# $as.Databases.GetByName("DB Name");

$out = "";

foreach($t in $db.Model.Tables) {
  foreach($M in $t.Measures) {
    $out += "// Measure defined in table [" + $t.Name + "] //" + "`n";
    $out += $M.Name + ":=" + $M.Expression + "`n";
  }
}

$as.Disconnect();
$out = $out.Replace("`t","  "); # I prefer spaces over tabs :-)
$out.TrimEnd() | Out-File $saveas;
```

Comment: Thank you! For the last section that you posted(Get Measures From Tabular), isn't there a flexibility to execute a query like you did in the first section(connecting to SQL Server). My intent is to frame and execute my own SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me

````
$connectionString =  $connectionString = “Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=TabularServerName;” 
$CubeQuery = 'SELECT * FROM $System.DBSchema_Tables';

$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$sqlCommand = $connection.CreateCommand() 

$sqlCommand.CommandText = $CubeQuery;

#SQL Adapter - get the results using the SQL Command
$sqlAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCommand
$dataSet = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$recordCount = $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)```
````

Comment: make sure query is in single quotes not double quotes